# Flutter - how create json array from List<String>?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have simply list in my flutter app:

```
 var items = List<String>();
 items.add('1');
 items.add('2');
 items.add('3');
```

I converted it to string:

```
 var values =items.join(',');
```

Result:

```
 "[1,2,3]"
```

But I need json array, like it:

```
 ["1","2","3"]
```

How I create it from my list? it should be easy - but I'm stuck. any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import 'dart:convert';

 var items = List<String>();
 items.add('1');
 items.add('2');
 items.add('3');
 // or even better: var items = ['1','2','3'];

 print(json.encode(items));
```

output:

```
["1","2","3"]
```